# What's the difference between project/build.sbt and project/BuildApp.scala?

Tags: sbt

What's the difference between `project/build.sbt` and `project/BuildApp.scala`? Can I create any of them interchangeably?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, equivalent to `project/BuildApp.scala` is `build.sbt`, *not* `project/build.sbt`. They *are* different in what they allow: [`.scala`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html) lets you do things [`.sbt`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html) doesn't, and they can be used together.

Comment: In that case, why to use .sbt at all?

Comment: Because it can be simpler than equivalent .scala.

Comment: So one can use `project/BuildApp.scala` without using `build.sbt` at all but not vise versa, correct?

Comment: No, you can use `build.sbt` by itself. You just won't be able to do some things which aren't needed for simple projects. From the docs: "The recommended approach is to define most configuration in .sbt files, using .scala files for task implementations or to share values, such as keys, across .sbt files."

Comment: once again `You just won't be able to do some things which aren't needed for simple projects` - So one can use project/BuildApp.scala without using build.sbt at all but not vise versa, correct?

Comment: Once again: you can do vice versa in most cases.

Comment: If  .scala lets you do things .sbt doesn't, why can't I use .scala always and not use .sbt at all? I don't care about simplicity.

Comment: "why can't I use .scala always and not use .sbt at all" You can.

Comment: Ok, that was my second comment.

Comment: I was responding to "but not vice versa".

Comment: You were responding "no".

Comment: Perhaps you should just read the docs: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html